# window.history - manage stack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, history.js

Let's say that the flow of my website is as follow:
a -> B -> C -> D
or
A -> B -> D

Let's say that I want to always get back from page D to page A. I can't use:

```
window.history.go(x)
```

because I have no idea how many steps it'll take to get from page A to page D.

Is there any way to remove steps between page A and D? Using native js or 'connected-react-router' library?
I don't want to redirect from D to A. It'd be great if I could just remove elements between D and A from history and user could navigate from D to A using 'back button' in his browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I don't want to redirect from D to A"

-> why thought?

`I think the best option is to redirect from D to A`

I know this don't answer the question but in your case user can go B - C - B - C ... etc

You can check if history in (B,C) then ignore but that's dirty...
Redirect is more convenient in your case